# ADODB Recordset filter not filtering record in Windows 7

Tags: vb6, adodb, recordset

I am using below Code :

```
Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset
------------------------------------
 If rs.State = 1 Then rs.Close
 com.ActiveConnection = con
 com.CommandText = "Select * from Table"

 On Error Resume Next
 rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
 rs.CursorType = adOpenDynamic

 Set rs = com.Execute 
 rs.Filter = "Filterdata"  //not filtering Recordset in Win-7
```

Above code working fine in WIN-XP.

**@Remou :**
 eg : Suppose  rs contain "A","B","C","A","C","A" values
 I am filtering data for geting "A" value only.
 My code will be : `rs.Filter = "A"`

Comment: Did you mean Filterdata, without the quotes? What is the content of Filterdata?

Comment: Try `"MyField=3"` instead of `"Filterdata"`. FYI, using `adUseClient` for cursor location always results in `adOpenStatic` for recordset type and it is using a forward-only "firehose" cursor to fetch it from server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the filter directly in the SQL query by a where clause - if it works, you can safely assume data is not the problem.
Also, AFAIK, the Filter command would expect fieldname = value syntax. How many fields are returned by the select statement?